# MySQL: Display customers who purchased in Month1 and either Month2 or Month3 but not both

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a complete newbie at MySQL so forgive me my ignorance.

I thought this would work but it's not.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_id
,       c_name
FROM    a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
WHERE   Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_one
AND     c_id IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT c_id
            FROM    a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
            WHERE   Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_two 
            XOR     Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_three )
;
```

So I tried this for comparison and it's not returning what I expected either:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_id
,       c_name
FROM    a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
WHERE   Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_two 
XOR     Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_three
;
```

I know I'm probably overlooking something simple and basic. :-/
Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please, provide some sample data from the table and your expected result.

Comment: Also, are you looking for completely unrelated dates of activity, or looking for specific sequential dates, such as ordered this month, as compared to last month and that two-months prior (i.e.: Apr compared to Mar and Feb) or just Apr 2012, vs Dec 2011 and Oct 2011 just being arbitrary dates

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your data looks like, but I'm assuming you have 2 tables, one with customer data and one with order data tied to the customer via and ID. So, something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer.id
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders
WHERE (Date_Format(orders.date, '%Y-%m') = @m_one AND Date_Format(orders.date, '%Y-%m') = @m_two)
OR (Date_Format(orders.date, '%Y-%m') = @m_one AND Date_Format(orders.date, '%Y-%m') = @m_three)
```

Obviously replace the table names with your own, but I believe you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Clexmond, thanks for responding. I'd considered an approach like that so I tried it after modifying to fit my situation but I get emtpy sets where there should be data.  I even limited it to the first line of the where clause as a test but same result. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm taking a class on this stuff, but the teacher is F'ing aweful. Her materials are full of typo's and errors. Getting a direct answer to a question can be like pulling teeth, she likes to beat around the bush.  Arrrrhhhhgggg.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue could be. Maybe try running a few queries just to make sure Date_Format is returning what you expect (aka what is in your @m_one variables). Something like: `SELECT Date_Format(date, '%Y-%m') FROM orders LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

The condition

```
WHERE   Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_two 
  XOR   Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_three )
```

doesn't do what you want. If you think about it, you'll realize that in this situation, XOR is identical to OR, because it's impossible for one order_date value to be in two different months. The WHERE clause is evaluated on each individual row, so on one order_date value at a time.

You do want order_date values that are in month @m_two OR in @m_three, but not all of them. You want to exclude those that appear in both. You could use a bunch of EXISTS and NOT EXISTS conditions, or you could do something like this. (It's somewhat hacky, so think it through more than I did.)

```
SELECT
  c_id, c_name
FROM a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
WHERE Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') IN (@m_one,@m_two,@m_three)
GROUP BY c_id, c_name
HAVING -- some order from month @m_one
  MAX(CASE WHEN Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_one THEN 1 END) = 1
AND -- having orders from exactly two distinct months of the three in question
  COUNT(DISTINCT Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m')) = 2;
```

In other words, this selects c_id, c_name values from the order table that appear at least once in @m_one and in exactly two of the three months in question.

Answer (score 0):

I find this approach more visible:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c_id,
    c_name
  FROM a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
 WHERE Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_one
   AND c_id IN (
    SELECT c_id
      FROM a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
     WHERE (
        (CASE WHEN Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_two THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN Date_Format(order_date, '%Y-%m') = @m_three THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1) )
;
```

I don't have MySQL database around to test it. Logic is really simple here:

- each of the [CASE ... END](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) expressions will yield `1` if month of order matches the given one;
- and according to your condition, only one of the months should be used, so sum should be `1`.